# Object.getPrototypeOf(classInstance) returns Object {}

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have this prototypical inheritance chain:

```js
function Class1() {};
Class1.prototype.name = 'Main Class';

function Class2() {};
Class2.prototype = Object.create(Class1.prototype);
Class2.prototype.constructor = Class2;

function Class3() {};
Class3.prototype = Object.create(Class1.prototype);
// Note missing reassignment of constructor for Class3

var class2Ins = new Class2();
var class3Ins = new Class3();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(class2Ins)); // Class2 { ... }
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(class3Ins)); // Object { ... }
```

I have a confusion around, how `Object.getPrototypeOf(class3Ins)` is an Object even though its prototype is Class3.

Comment: IIUC... I'm not surprised the debugger is displaying something weird in this case. `Class2`'s prototype's constructor is `Class2`? I don't think that kind of thing is likely to ever show up in real code.

Comment: Interesting question - if you assign `Class3` a constructor, this problem is fixed, but I'm curious as to why this happens when we don't give it a manually constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit unclear of how prototypal delegation works in JS.

First off, when I run your code in my browser, I get the following output:

```
Object { constructor: Class2() } 
Object {  }
```

You might want to check if your output is the same or if it differs.

---

Now, the concepts.

> When a function is created, the JS engine creates an anonymous object and binds the 2 as follows:
>
> ```
> function foo(){} // user created a function
>
> /* The JS engine binds an anonymous object */
> // foo.prototype = {};
> // foo.prototype.constructor = foo;
> ```

Also,

> When an object is created by a *constructor function* using `new`,
>   the `[[Prototype]]` (or `.__proto__`) of the created object is
>   **set to the anonymous object referenced (pointed to) by the `function.prototype`**

And

> The `Object.create()` method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

---

Okay, so what does all this mean?

Let's break down your code into chunks, as if we were the engine.

```
function Class1() {};
/*
  bind anonymous object:

  Class1.prototype = {};
  Class1.prototype.constructor = Class1;
*/
Class1.prototype.name = 'Main Class';


function Class2() {};
/*
  bind anonymous object:

  Class2.prototype = {};
  Class2.prototype.constructor = Class2;
*/
Class2.prototype = Object.create(Class1.prototype);
/*
  create new object with prototype as the specified object:

  Class2.prototype = {};
  Object.setPrototypeOf(Class2.prototype, Class1.prototype);
*/
Class2.prototype.constructor = Class2;


function Class3() {};
/*
  bind anonymous object:

  Class3.prototype = {};
  Class3.prototype.constructor = Class3;
*/
Class3.prototype = Object.create(Class1.prototype);
/*
  create new object with prototype as the specified object:

  Class3.prototype = {};
  Object.setPrototypeOf(Class3.prototype, Class1.prototype);
*/
// Note missing reassignment of constructor for Class3


var class2Ins = new Class2();
/*
  set [[Prototype]] of the created object to object referenced by the function.prototype:

  Object.setPrototypeOf(class2Ins, class2.prototype);
*/
var class3Ins = new Class3();
/*
  set [[Prototype]] of the created object to object referenced by the function.prototype:

  Object.setPrototypeOf(class3Ins, class3.prototype);
*/
```

#### What's the end result?

1. `Object.getPrototypeOf(class3Ins)` (in simple terms, `class2Ins.__proto__`) is the same as `Class2.prototype`
2. `Class2.prototype` is an object created by `Object.create(Class1.prototype)`.
3. `Class2.prototype.__proto__` is the same as `Class1.prototype`.

1. `class3Ins.__proto__` is the same as `Class3.prototype`
2. `Class3.prototype` is an object created by `Object.create(Class1.prototype)`.
3. `Class3.prototype.__proto__` is the same as `Class1.prototype`.

And the reason why `Object.getPrototypeOf(class3Ins)` is empty, is that `Object.create` creates an empty object.

---

If you are still confused, please visit: http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-prototype/

It is a great resource to understand prototype concepts in JS.